# Limit search results based on path patterns

Tags: 7, search

We are running Drupal's internal search functionality but wish to limit it the results between a few 'sections'  of the site. I'm defining sections here based on URL patterns.

For example, suppose you had the following urls for a site.

- http://example.com/artist_bios/
- http://example.com/musician_bios/

I don't want to clutter search results with other irrlevlant information.

You want to know who is starring in Thursday's show vs the weekend special. Other times, you want to know who plays the cello in the ensemble.

**Question:** Is it possible to limit search results based on a URL pattern for something like the above example?

Comment: If the pages in question are for example Views pages. You could easily make an Exposed filter to search within the views result set for all returned items related to the page.

Comment: Hm! That may be a good method. I guess the factor is *how much* content you'd have to sort through. Where would you guess is a logical cut off 500 / 1,000 / 10,000 / 50,000 nodes? Throw that in the answers below. That may be a good method -- if not for me, someone else looking to do the same.